# error lvalue when use singleton contain array of pointer

Tags: c++, singleton, lvalue

My singleton like

```
class ValueLstNode {
private:
    ZwNode* m_pZwNode[32];
public:
    ValueLstNode();
    ValueLstNode(const ValueLstNode& rhs);
    static ValueLstNode& GetInstance();
    virtual ~ValueLstNode();

    ValueLstNode& operator= (const ValueLstNode& rhs);

    ZwNode_p GetNode    (int Posion) const;
    ZwNode_p operator[] (int Posion);
    const ZwNode_p operator[] (int byPosion) const;
};
```

And file .cpp

```
ValueLstNode::ValueLstNode() {
    for (u32_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        m_pZwNode[i] = NULL;
    }
}

ValueLstNode::ValueLstNode(
    const ValueLstNode& rhs
) {
    for (u32_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        m_pZwNode[i] = rhs.m_pZwNode[i];
    }
}

ValueLstNode&
ValueLstNode::operator= (
    const ValueLstNode& rhs
) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ZW_MAX_NODES; i++) {
        m_pZwNode[i] = rhs.m_pZwNode[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

ValueLstNode::~ValueLstNode() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ZW_MAX_NODES; i++) {
        if (m_pZwNode[i] != NULL) {
            delete m_pZwNode[i];
            m_pZwNode[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

ValueLstNode&
ValueLstNode::GetInstance() {
    static ValueLstNode m_instance;
    return m_instance;
}

ZwNode*
ValueLstNode::operator[] (
    int Posion
) {
    return m_pZwNode[Posion];
}

const ZwNode*
ValueLstNode::operator[] (
    int Posion
) const {
    return m_pZwNode[Posion];
}
```

But

```
ValueLstNode m_ValueLstNode = ValueLstNode::GetInstance();
m_ValueLstNode[0] = NULL;
```

I get error: lvalue required ...
How to solve this. Help me.
Thank & rg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have created isn't actually conforming the idiomatic *Singleton Pattern*. Lets see:

```
class ValueLstNode {
   // ...
public:
    ValueLstNode(); // You allow pulic construction of new instances
    ValueLstNode(const ValueLstNode& rhs); // You allow new instances as copies 
    static ValueLstNode& GetInstance();
    virtual ~ValueLstNode();

    ValueLstNode& operator= (const ValueLstNode& rhs); // Well, may be the right intend,
                                                       // but not really idiomatic for a 
                                                       // singleton

    ZwNode_p GetNode    (int Posion) const;            // You return copies of your 
                                                       // internally managed elements?
    ZwNode_p operator[] (int Posion);                  // ^^^^ That
    const ZwNode_p operator[] (int byPosion) const;    // ^^^^ That
};
```

As you want to operate on a *Singleton*, you need to keep state within that single class.

So you need to return class members to manipulate as references:

```
ZwNode_p& operator[] (int Posion);
const ZwNode_p& operator[] (int Posion) const;
```

Also your *Singleton* implementation should explicitly deny creating copies of that class:

```
class ValueLstNode {
    ValueLstNode(const ValueLstNode&) = delete;
    ValueLstNode& operator=(const ValueLstNode&) = delete;
};
```

and take a reference if you need it:

```
ValueLstNode& m_ValueLstNode = ValueLstNode::GetInstance();
```

---

Though, I don't fully get the use case of a *Singleton Pattern* applied from your naming. The semantics feel broken.

I don't see how it makes sense `ValueLstNode` should need to be a *Singleton*. Did you mean to create a *Factory Pattern* rather?

Comment: Contructor and copies is public, eclips notice error. I can't private contructor and copies.